# Find the area of a sphere inside a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, area

I want to find the area of the portion of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4z$ inside the function $x^2+y^2=z$ using double integrals. The graph would be something like this:

[image]

Because of the nature of this functions, I assume the best way would be to find the area projected on the plane yOz in the first octant and multiply it by 4. Hence, the area would be:
$$4\int \:\int \:\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)^2}dA$$
However, I failed every time I tried to solve this, so I would appreciate any help. I know that he correct answer is $4\pi $.

Comment: What does it mean to be "inside" a function? Functions don't have sides.

Comment: With inside a function, the problem is talking about the area of the portion of the sphere (red function) inside the blue function. In other words, what I marked on this image: https://ibb.co/fqvGQ5h

Comment: Functions don't have sides, and functions don't have colors. You'll never get math if you don't learn how to use mathematical terms carefully and correctly.

Comment: I'm afraid I must tell you that if you can not contribute in any way with your comments it would be better if you kept them for yourself. Thank you trying to help anyway. Have a good day

Comment: If you think my comments are not making a contribution to your education, it just shows how badly you need to engage with them and take them to heart. I have led you to the water, but I cannot make you drink. Good luck – you'll need it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You’re acting too harsh. Mathematical terms are simply a way to convey information. If you have another way to convey that same information, such as providing a diagram as OP did, then you’ve successfully achieved your goal: convey information. OP thought it was easier and more intuitive to provide a diagram rather than a bunch of complicated inequalities. I don’t see anything wrong with doing that since he was able to convey the problem sufficiently.

Comment: @Spencer, no inequalities, complicated or otherwise, are necessary here, just careful use of English. Instead of the nonsensical inside of a function, how hard is it to write, the inside of *the graph* of a function; instead of "the blue function", to write "the blue *graph*"? The distinction between a function and its graph is a very important one, and the student who doesn't get the distinction is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=f(x,y)=2+\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$, then $f_x=-\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}$ and $f_y=-\dfrac{y}{4-x^2-y^2}$.

When we solve for $r^2+z^2=4z$ for $r>0$ and $z$ to get $r=\sqrt3$ and $z=3$

The surface area is $$\int\int_D\sqrt{1+f^2_x+f^2_y}\ dA$$
$$\int\int_D\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}\ dA=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt3}\dfrac{2r}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}\ drd\theta=-2(2\pi)\sqrt{4-r^2}\bigg|_0^{\sqrt3}=4\pi$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!